# Skipping BLE service discovery

Tags: android, performance, service, bluetooth-lowenergy, service-discovery

I am trying to minimize the total connection + write time to a BLE device. The BLE module is develop by a company I work for, so I already know all the services and characteristics of the device.

So far, the connection time + service discovery time is too long (it is about 800ms, where the requirement is to be 500 ms top). I've tried to skip the service discovery, and to do so, I've created the characteristics and services manually in the code (use reflection to set protected properties etc), and I can "technically" by pass the service discovery.

The problem is, that if I do so, the first packet takes about 300 ms, where with the service discovery, the discovery takes about 280 ms and the first packet takes 20 ms, so it seems that the service discovery is performed no matter what, just later, even if I don't call it directly - is my assumption right?
If so, is there a way to bypass the discovery at all?

Would appreciate any help, so far I could not found any helpful information online, and those 300 ms are critial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android does a service discovery even if you not tell it to.

You have three options:

1. Bond your devices. Then android will not perform any service discovery at all (except for the first connection).
2. Optimize your GATT db. Throw away characteristic and descriptors you don't need and if you have custom services, try to merge as many characteristic as possible etc.
3. Optimize link layer if you have hardware where doing so is possible, in the way that you respond to each GATT request in the same connection event (within 150 us) rather than responding in the next connection event. Theoretically this should improve speed by 2 times. An example where this is possible is Nordic Semiconductor's nrf52.

Comment: The GATT is optimized (only required service and characteristics exists), before that optimization  it toke ~550 ms to do service discovery. Will point the firmware/hardware team to the link layer and report results. Thank you

Comment: One more thing you can try: Increase MTU to some higher value than the default of 23 (for example 512). That way more services/characteristics can fit in each response, reducing the number of connection events.